# How to check that environment variable is set but also really exists?

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I have a script that has to check whether the environment variable FILE was set but also whether the path to it really exists. This is what I googled so far:

```
if env | grep -q ^FILE=
then
   echo env variable is already exported
else
   echo env variable was not exported
   exit 1
fi
```

Which works if the variable is set correctly, but if the path doesn't exist, it runs into error on the first if statement. How should I modify the statements to check for it? My task is to create the path if it doesn't exist from the script.

Comment: I cannot understand how the existence of a path can make run that script into error. What is the error message?

Comment: If I export a path that doesn't really exist I get an error from grep `grep: /home/user/Desktop/something/record: No such file or directory`. My task is to create the path and also a new file if the exported path doesn't exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since we're writing shell code, environment variables are just normal variables.

```
if [ -f "$FILE" ]; then
    echo env variable is already exported
else
    echo env variable was not exported
fi
```

I don't see why you would have gotten an error when `FILE` wasn't exported with the above code, but if you were to test like this: `if [ -f $FILE ]` (i.e. without the quotation marks) you would run into an error when `FILE` isn't set.

Comment: I never even thought of working with it as an ordinary variable, I was always trying to push in `env` because I had the notion it's different from a regular variable somehow. Thank you for clearing that!

Comment: They are slightly different; they have their `export` attribute set. All that means, though, is that when you start a new command, variables with the `export` attribute are copied into the environment of that command. Otherwise, an "environment" variable is just a shell variable that is initialized from the environment on startup.

Answer (score 2):

Environment variables are different in that they reside in the environment block, but other than that you can use them the same as any other variable in `bash`.  That's not true for all shells, `csh`/`tcsh` (C-shell) does treat them differently.

There are tests for checking the existence of a variable (you don't need quotes if you use `[[`) :

```
[[ -z $FILE ]] && echo '$FILE empty'
[[ -n $FILE ]] || echo '$FILE empty'
```

From bash 4:

```
[[ -v $FILE ]] || echo '$FILE not set'
```

By the way, be careful of using uppercase variable names, they can collide with those used by the shell.